# maximum posible cells in formatting in Excel

Tags: office-js

would like to know what is the maximum number of cells that we can apply formatting to a Table in Excel using office js ?

Am trying to format using - {row: i, column: j} and  beyond 1100 cells, its throwing an error message like - ' No more fonts may be applied.' Please close some other documents and try again.

For cells less than 1100 , the formatting works just fine.

Note - cells 1100 => there are 1100 records where only one column needs conditional formatting.

Comment: What does your code look like?

Comment: Also, what host are you using (Office 2013 vs Office 2016 / Office 365?).  In case of the latter, you'll probably be better off with formatting using the newer host-specific APIs (`Excel.run` pattern, see https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/excel/excel-add-ins-javascript-programming-overview?product=excel, instead of what I assume is the `Office.context.document._____Async` call that you're making today).